# Javascript event listeners/variable passing in separate files

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am completely new to javascript and am struggling with this. I am trying to get a token out of this front end and into my python script. Any help is super appreciated.

I have index.html and index.js. Users click a button to use a SSO and login. The token is then stored in a global variable in index.js. I also have server.js which is listening.

I have successfully been able to write a JSON file from server.js, but I can not figure out how to wait until the login is successfully completed and then pass the token string from index.js to server.js. Can anyone help me figure out what to do? Thanks in advance.

```
//index.js
document.getElementById('login-btn').addEventListener('click', () => {
      /***
        Returns a promise which resolves with a usertoken when a user successfully authenticates and authorizes
      ***/
      token.authorize().then(UserToken => {
        console.log(`Authorized, user-token: ${UserToken}`); ## This line is not printing in console.
      });
    });

    // expose our instance globally for testing
    window.token = token; ##this is the string I want to pass to server.js
```

I know that the authorization works as I'm able to use other functionality in the front-end, I just can't figure out how to wait for the token to be generated and then pass it from index.js to server.js

Comment: if you want to post data from javascript, search for something like: "Post data from JavaScript" on Google or here.

Comment: Don't really need to post data. I need to figure out how to wait to print until the authorization is finished and theres a value in "token"

Comment: If `console.log(`Authorized, user-token: ${UserToken}`)` is not printing, your `token.authorize()` does not succeed. For starters add .catch(e => console.log('error:', e)) after `.then` before `;`. If your promise fails, you will see the error message.

Comment: Appreciate your insight. Will give that a shot, thanks!

Comment: @IgorShmukler I did add that line. The authorization was successful once again but still nothing printed to console. This is my complete inexperience with js, but if I put anything in the console.log(anytext) on the server.js file it will show in console. Nothing I put in index.js shows in console at all.